# factorygirl association validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :contacts

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :program

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
  sequence(.... 
   ...
  program_id 1  #foreign key
  program       #association

(byebug) contact
Contact id: 949, display_name: "Contact-3", business_phone: "1234567894", fax_number: "1234567894", created_at: "2017-03-05 00:43:24", updated_at: "2017-03-05 00:43:24", first_name: "First-4", last_name: "Last-4", middle_initial: "4", email: "Email4@Something.Com", program_id: 1193, 287g: nil, active: true, call_office_id: 4
```

The program_id is 1193 in the contact record created with the contact factory but the program table has only four records with ids 1-4.  Not sure where 1193 originates from.  At this point the rspec test more or less succeeds.  But once the validation code below gets added to the contact model the rspec test fails.

Contact Model with Association Validation Added For Program

```
class ProgramValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.program.nil?
      record.errors[:base] << "Program cannot be blank"
    end
  end
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
  validates_with ProgramValidator
```

Running rspec now it complains that "Program cannot be blank".  Question: how can the contact factory get created to satisfy the validation? Why are associations so friggin difficult, much harder than creating the associations in ROR. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

According to Factory Girl's documentation try something like:

```
factory :contact do
  # ...
  association :program, factory: :program
end
```

For more ifnromation about Factory Girl's associations please follow the link:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  program       #association
```

creates new Program record, which is attached as association (with some other id, which can be also 1193 or any other id).

If you don't want any new program record to be created, just leave `program_id 1` only in your factory class. Also, remember that you run your tests in empty database.
This factory class definition will work if you create Program record, for example, before your test suite and specify explicitly its ID as 1.